# JS wrong encoding after HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, glassfish

I have a JSF application hosted in glassfish V2 final. The main JSP uses an external js file that contains some strings with áéíóú chars.

If I navigate the main page this way:

host/AppName

The encoding of all the main page works but if I call it this way:

host/AppName/faces/mypage.jsp

The encoding of almost all page is Ok but all the strings from the js files lose their encoding.

What I have tried is:

1 Set the encoding of the js file when including:

```
<script src="res/javascript/converterScript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

2 Using `&oacute;` in this strings but when the JSP is rendered I get `W&oacute;ord`.

3 Changed the app server default encoding. Didn't work.

This are the first lines of my JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="res/javascript/converterScript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

If I download res/javascript/converterScript.js and ask for codification using the command `file converterScript.js` I get UTF-8 Unicode in a Linux machine but when I inspect it using firebug directly from browser all special chars are lost.

The strange part is that the only part that is not working are the strings from this file.
Im out of ideas, any help is appreciated.